# Datatable doesn't work in wordpress theme - twenty sixteen

Tags: wordpress

We have built a web-site using twentysixteen wordpress theme.

I have created a sample page with html content as below

The below html works fine when i saved in my local system and browse via chrome. However the same datatable is not rendering properly when i inserted in the word press page.

Sample HTML is as follows

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  
 href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/r-2.1.0/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-
   2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/r-2.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    scrollY: 300,
    paging: false
} );
} );
</script>

<style>
div.container { max-width: 1200px }
</style>
</head>

<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>8422</td>
            <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
            <td>1562</td>
            <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric</td>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
            <td>6224</td>
            <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi</td>
            <td>Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
            <td>5407</td>
            <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle</td>
            <td>Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
            <td>4804</td>
            <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod</td>
            <td>Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
            <td>9608</td>
            <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona</td>
            <td>Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
            <td>6200</td>
            <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen</td>
            <td>Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
            <td>2360</td>
            <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya</td>
            <td>Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
            <td>1667</td>
            <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena</td>
            <td>Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
            <td>3814</td>
            <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn</td>
            <td>Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
            <td>9497</td>
            <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde</td>
            <td>Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
            <td>6741</td>
            <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley</td>
            <td>Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
            <td>3597</td>
            <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana</td>
            <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
            <td>1581</td>
            <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
            <td>3059</td>
            <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria</td>
            <td>Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
            <td>1721</td>
            <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
            <td>2558</td>
            <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai</td>
            <td>Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
            <td>2290</td>
            <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette</td>
            <td>Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
            <td>1937</td>
            <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri</td>
            <td>Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
            <td>6154</td>
            <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar</td>
            <td>Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
            <td>8330</td>
            <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris</td>
            <td>Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
            <td>3023</td>
            <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica</td>
            <td>Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
            <td>5797</td>
            <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
            <td>8822</td>
            <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
            <td>9239</td>
            <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden</td>
            <td>Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
            <td>1314</td>
            <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
            <td>2947</td>
            <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou</td>
            <td>Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
            <td>8899</td>
            <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
            <td>2769</td>
            <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki</td>
            <td>Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
            <td>6832</td>
            <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott</td>
            <td>Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
            <td>3606</td>
            <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
            <td>2860</td>
            <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena</td>
            <td>Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
            <td>8240</td>
            <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td>Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
            <td>7031</td>
            <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope</td>
            <td>Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
            <td>6318</td>
            <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
            <td>7580</td>
            <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
            <td>1042</td>
            <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
            <td>2120</td>
            <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
            <td>6222</td>
            <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
            <td>9383</td>
            <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
            <td>8327</td>
            <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
            <td>2927</td>
            <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
            <td>8352</td>
            <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
            <td>7439</td>
            <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
            <td>4389</td>
            <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
            <td>3431</td>
            <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
            <td>3990</td>
            <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
            <td>1016</td>
            <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
            <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
            <td>8196</td>
            <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>6373</td>
            <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please kindly help me on how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you need to sort your scripts in a proper way. And in WordPress you need to insert your scripts using functions.php file

Comment: @Samuel You have not accepted answers on any of your questions... If the answer solves your issue you should accept it ( it will increase your and answerers reputation  )

Comment: You can also upvote but accepting or commenting that answer doesn't solve your issue is pretty important, it is fine to know if the answer did not help but no response is a bit annoying for the answerer 